# Estimate the fundamental frequency using cepstral analysis

Tags: signal-processing, fft

Wrote a frequency domain pitch detection algorithm in C and now I'm trying to estimate the fundamental frequency. I have the maximum magnitude bin from the Fourier Transform, but that can also be an harmonic not necessary F0. I read somewhere that it is possible to estimate F0 using [cepstral analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cepstrum). So, here are the steps I follow:

1. Take time domain buffer x, make a windowed copy w.
2. FTTw = FFT(w)
3. a = Log of square magnitude of FTTw
4. FTTa = FFT(a)
5. b = square magnitude of FTTa
6. **Estimate fundamental using b**

I'm having trouble with the last step (6). The magnitudes in b are pretty high and I'm not sure I fully understand what they represent (quefrencies?) and most of all how can I estimate the fundamental based on them.

Any advice is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Since this is more DSP-related than programming-related you might want to try http://dsp.stackexchange.com instead of http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Done that, was there several hours, got no answer/comment. I guess the community is still small, so I tried my luck here :)

Comment: You probably need to be patient - give it 24 hours or so - different time zones etc. If you get an answer here it will probably be from someone who is active on http://dsp.stackexchange.com anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the peak in the cepstrum (on the quefrency axis) tells you the pitch period of your original signal. The *magnitude* of the peak is not particularly important.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I have one more small question: can I make a quadratic interpolation to increase accuracy between the peaks in the cepstrum or should I come back to the original FFT data with the known frequency and do it there. (sorry for adding another question to the original :D, but I saw you helped others on SO regarding DSP issues and I thought you may know)

Comment: Probably a better way to do this is to zero pad your original FFT input - this gives you an interpolated spectrum with higher *resolution*. Or just use a bigger time window if you really do need higher *accuracy*.